# Find a specific text in a file, cut it from the current file and then paste it another file

Tags: ruby, regex, file-io

I am trying find a certain piece of code in a .rb file, once found I want to cut it from the current file and then paste it into another existing file. So an an example:

file1.rb has the following:

```
RSpec.describe 'Get Test  Data' do

  it "should get test data for build" do |example|
    log_start_test("#{example.description}")
    get_test_data
    log_complete_test("#{example.description}")
  end

end
```

I want to find `it "should get test data for build" do |example|` and then cut this piece of code:

```
 it "should get test data for build" do |example|
    log_start_test("#{example.description}")
    get_test_data
    log_complete_test("#{example.description}")
  end
```

and paste it another file. 
So far I have been able to find the desired string using something like this:

```
    File.open("#{Dir.pwd}/spec/api/test_data_search_spec.rb") do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|
        if line =~ /do |example|/
          puts "Found root #{line}"
        end
      end
    end
```

Just not able to figure out the exact regular expression to find the required block and then how do i do a cut from a file and paste into another one? Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions are not suited to parse code.

you could use [method_source](https://github.com/banister/method_source) as an existing solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @phoet. That would have worked for specific methods but I was looking more for moving rspec example code block around. But here is what I ended up using as an example:

```
  def move_example_block(example_description, source_file,destination_file)
    lines = File.readlines("#{Dir.pwd}/spec/api/#{source_file}_spec.rb")
    desired_block = lines.join[/it "should get test data for build" do(.*)end/m]
    temp = desired_block.freeze
    puts temp
    filename = "#{Dir.pwd}/spec/api/#{source_file}_spec.rb"
    text = File.read(filename)
    puts = text.gsub(/it "#{example_description}" do(.*)end/m, "end")
    File.open(filename, "w") { |file| file << puts }

    filename = "#{Dir.pwd}/spec/api/#{destination_file}_spec.rb"
    text = File.read(filename)
    puts = text.gsub(/end/, temp)
    File.open(filename, "w") { |file| file << puts }
  end
```